# How to document Python function parameters with Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I'm trying to clean up my python code documentation, and decided to use [sphinx-doc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html) because it looks good.  I like how I can reference other classes and methods with tags like:

```
:class:`mymodule.MyClass` About my class.
:meth:`mymodule.MyClass.myfunction` And my cool function
```

I'm trying to figure out though how to document parameter names in a function, so that if I have a function like:

```
def do_this(parameter1, parameter2):
   """
   I can describe do_this.

   :something?:`parameter1` And then describe the parameter.

   """
```

What's the best practice for this?

**Update:**

The correct syntax is:

```
def do_this(parameter1, parameter2):
   """
   I can describe do_this.

   :something parameter1: And then describe the variable
   """
```

Comment: Those are called "info field lists". See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547849/good-examples-of-python-docstrings-for-sphinx

Comment: Check out the [Napolean](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/napoleon.html) extension for Sphinx, which allows doc strings in either [Google or Numpy style](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/napoleon.html#google-vs-numpy), both of which look nicer that plain Sphinx.

Comment: Also of interest: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically "function variables" are called parameters ;).

It's documented here: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#signatures

And the answer is `:param ________`

**EDIT** Disclaimer: I've never used or heard of sphinx... This post is mostly a "what words to search for."  Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks... I was searching for the wrong thing.  I had tried param at some point, but kept getting errors, and didn't realize the syntax was not :param:`variable1`, but :param variable1:

Comment: http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#id1 and https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#function-definitions

Comment: Conventions for documenting complex parameters (lists, dicts etc) - https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html

Comment: @Crisfole, I think the link in your answer doesn't point to the right page.

Answer (score 7):

Adding this answer to consolidate options:

[pydoc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) is basic with no special formatting

[epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) uses the format '@param var:'

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is oriented for a larger range of languages

[Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) uses the format ':param type var:'. Also see [more examples](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#python-signatures). This was used to create the [Python 3.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/).

Answer (score 3):

**How to document types**

It is also worth noting the old syntax `:type parameter2: MyClass` for parameter type, also documented at https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#signatures

But with Python 3 `typing` we can just:

main.py

```
class MyClass:
    """
    This class does that.
    """
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

def do_this(parameter1: int, parameter2: MyClass):
   """
   This function does this.

   :param parameter1: my favorite int
   :param parameter2: my favorite class
   """
   return parameter1 + parameter2.i
```

build.sh

```
sphinx-build . out
```

conf.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
extensions = [ 'sphinx.ext.autodoc' ]
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members': True,
}
```

index.rst

```
.. automodule:: main
```

requirements.txt

```
Sphinx==6.1.3
```

Output on `out/index.html`:

[image]

Note how it correctly links the parameter type to the documentation of the class `MyClass`.

**Make types appear next to the description instead**

Can be done by adding the following to your `conf.py`:

```
autodoc_typehints = "description"
```

[image]

See also: [How to make Sphinx show Python 3 typing type hints next to the argument description instead of on the function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071573/python-3-sphinx-doesnt-show-type-hints-correctly)

**`:type:` example**

For reference, the pre-`typing` approach looked like:

```
def do_this(parameter1, parameter2):
   """
   This function does this.

   :param parameter1: my favorite int
   :type parameter1: int
   :param parameter2: my favorite class
   :type parameter2: MyClass
   """
   return parameter1 + parameter2.i
```

which produces output identical to the `autodoc_typehints = "description"` version with `typing`, but with more duplication as we have to type (no pun) `parameter1` and `parameter2` yet again.

**Other useful typing related things to know**

- how to represent multiple types: [How to express multiple types for a single parameter or a return value in docstrings that are processed by Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647966/how-to-express-multiple-types-for-a-single-parameter-or-a-return-value-in-docstr)
- how to link to the documentation of types of external projects: [Specifying targets for intersphinx links to numpy, scipy, and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538983/specifying-targets-for-intersphinx-links-to-numpy-scipy-and-matplotlib)

Tested on Ubuntu 22.10, Python 3.10.7.

Comment: To get more readable function signature documentations, check also `autodoc_typehints = "description"` Sphinx option https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa blasphemy! Types next to signature are the True path.

Comment: The default option is unreadable if your function has any complex types as arguments or more than three arguments.