# Specifying targets for intersphinx links to numpy, scipy, and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, python-sphinx

Following the documentation for setting up Sphinx documentation links between packages, I have added

```
intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('http://docs.python.org/2', None),
                       'numpy': ('http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/', None),
                       'scipy': ('http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/', None),
                       'matplotlib': ('http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/', None)}
```

to my `conf.py`, but can't seem to get links to any project other than Python itself to work. For example

```
:term:`svg graphics <matplotlib:svg>`
```

just takes me to the index page, without adding the expected `#term-svg` anchor, and I can't even locate the glossary for `scipy` or figure out how to determine what `:ref:`s or `:term:`s are supported by a package.

Where can I find instructions on how to specify targets for `:ref:`s and `:term:`s in `numpy`, `scipy`, and `matplotlib`?

---

For that matter, how do I link to Sphinx itself? Adding

```
intersphinx_mapping['sphinx'] = ('http://sphinx-doc.org/', None)
```

and

```
:ref:`Intersphinx <intersphinx>`
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Using ``:term:`svg graphics <matplotlib:svg>` `` works fine for me. I cannot explain why you only get to the index page. And if you want to link to the intersphinx documentation page, use the module name: ``:mod:`Intersphinx <sphinx.ext.intersphinx>` ``.

Comment: This answer shows how you can find the available intersphinx targets for a documentation project: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30981554/407651.

Comment: Is it possible that you're using an older version of sphinx?  As I recall, older versions only support referencing *identifiers*, but not `:ref:` and similar.  Have you tried just doing something like ``In python you can `open` a file ``?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly write cross-references to external documentation with intersphinx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939867/how-to-properly-write-cross-references-to-external-documentation-with-intersphin)

Comment: I've found the [sphobjinv](https://pypi.org/project/sphobjinv/) command line tool to be extremely useful for this task.

Answer (score 25):

> Where can I find instructions on how to specify targets for `:ref:`s and `:term:`s in `numpy`, `scipy`, and `matplotlib`?

I have a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/bskinn/0e164963428d4b51017cebdb6cda5209) with a handful of `intersphinx` mappings, which now includes all of `numpy`, `scipy` and `matplotlib`.  You should be able to use these entries directly in [`intersphinx_mapping`](https://github.com/bskinn/sphobjinv/blob/v1.0/doc/source/conf.py#L414-L418), within your `conf.py`. If anyone has suggestions for further entries to be added to this list, please feel free to post requests into the comments of the Gist.

For all of these packages, per [fgoudra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753166/4376000) I highly recommend using [`sphobjinv`](https://github.com/bskinn/sphobjinv) to search within the `objects.inv` file for each library.  (Full disclosure: I am the author of `sphobjinv`.) The [`suggest`](https://sphobjinv.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0/cli/suggest.html) mode of the CLI interface is specifically designed to provide the information needed to compose intersphinx cross-references.

---

**`numpy` is complicated.** Sometimes you need a fully-qualified name, e.g.:

```
:func:`numpy.cross`
```

Other times (for C functions, for example) you can just reference the function's base name BUT you have to explicitly indicate the domain, e.g.:

```
:c:func:`PyArray_InnerProduct`
```

Yet other times you may have to reference the custom `np` domain, e.g.:

```
:np:func:`numpy.ma.append`
```

There's really no way to know what the right syntax is without consulting the `objects.inv`.

**`scipy` is roughly as inscrutable as `numpy`.** Things are further complicated by the introduction of numerous custom domains for the various `scipy` subpackages, e.g.:

```
:scipy-optimize:func:`scipy.integrate.newton_cotes`
```

**For `matplotlib`,** it appears you always have to provide the (quite verbose) fully-specified object name in the reference, e.g.:

```
:meth:`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`
```

All of the `matplotlib` code objects seem to reside in the default `py` domain, however, which simplifies things somewhat.

**For any of these,** if you're having trouble getting a link to construct properly, the first thing I fall back to is using the generic `:obj:` role, e.g.:

```
:obj:`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`
```

This will construct an `intersphinx` link regardless of the role in which a particular object was defined, though I think you still have to correctly specify any relevant non-default domain. If the reference doesn't work properly with an `:obj:` role, then there's an error in the object name or the domain somewhere. Check for typos in both places.

Answer (score 9):

In case this is still an issue..
you need to leave out the slash at the end of the URL:

```python
intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('http://docs.python.org/2', None),
                       'numpy': ('http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy', None),
                       'scipy': ('http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference', None),
                       'matplotlib': ('http://matplotlib.org/stable', None)}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to manually specify which inventory to look. For example, if `intersphinx_mapping['sphinx'] = ('http://sphinx-doc.org/', None)`
does not work, you can always download the inventory and manually append it to the mapping (e.g. download from http://sphinx-doc.org/objects.inv, save the binary file in your docs and append the path to it in the mapping; this will give something like:

`intersphinx_mapping['sphinx'] = ('http://sphinx-doc.org/', ('objects.inv', ), )`

To verify if a reference exists within the inventory, you can explore the binary with the [sphobjinv](http://sphinx-objectsinv-encoderdecoder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python package and check where is the reference you want.

This may not be a solution to your problem but can help to debug some things.

Answer (score 4):

An additional way to know how to do cross reference is with the [sphobjinv](https://sphobjinv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module.

You can search local or even remote inventory files (with fuzzy matching). For instance with scipy:

```
$ sphobjinv suggest -t 90 -u https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/objects.inv "signal.convolve2d"

Remote inventory found.

:py:function:`scipy.signal.convolve2d`
:std:doc:`generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d`
```

Note that you may need to use `:py:func:` and not `:py:function:` (I'd be happy to know why).