# How to properly write cross-references to external documentation with intersphinx?

Tags: python, opencv, documentation, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to add cross-references to external API into my documentation but I'm facing three different behaviors.

I am using sphinx(1.3.1) with Python(2.7.3) and my intersphinx mapping is configured as:

```
{
'python': ('https://docs.python.org/2.7', None),
'numpy': ('http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/', None),
'cv2' : ('http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/', None),
'h5py' : ('http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/', None)
}
```

I have no trouble writing a cross-reference to numpy API with `` :class:`numpy.ndarray` `` or `` :func:`numpy.array` `` which gives me, as expected, something like [numpy.ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray).

However, with h5py, the only way I can have a link generated is if I omit the module name. For example, `` :class:`Group` `` (or `` :class:`h5py:Group` ``) gives me [Group](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#Group) but `` :class:`h5py.Group` `` fails to generate a link.

Finally, I cannot find a way to write a working cross-reference to OpenCV API, none of these seems to work:

```
:func:`cv2.convertScaleAbs`
:func:`cv2:cv2.convertScaleAbs`
:func:`cv2:convertScaleAbs`
:func:`convertScaleAbs`
```

How to properly write cross-references to external API, or configure intersphinx,  to have a generated link as in the numpy case?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I gave another try on trying to understand the content of an `objects.inv` file and hopefully this time I inspected numpy and h5py instead of only OpenCV's one.

### How to read an intersphinx inventory file

Despite the fact that I couldn't find anything useful about reading the content of an `object.inv` file, it is actually very simple with the intersphinx module.

```
from sphinx.ext import intersphinx
import warnings


def fetch_inventory(uri):
    """Read a Sphinx inventory file into a dictionary."""
    class MockConfig(object):
        intersphinx_timeout = None  # type: int
        tls_verify = False

    class MockApp(object):
        srcdir = ''
        config = MockConfig()

        def warn(self, msg):
            warnings.warn(msg)

    return intersphinx.fetch_inventory(MockApp(), '', uri)


uri = 'http://docs.python.org/2.7/objects.inv'

# Read inventory into a dictionary
inv = fetch_inventory(uri)
# Or just print it
intersphinx.debug(['', uri])
```

### File structure (numpy)

After inspecting numpy's one, you can see that keys are domains:

```
[u'np-c:function',
 u'std:label',
 u'c:member',
 u'np:classmethod',
 u'np:data',
 u'py:class',
 u'np-c:member',
 u'c:var',
 u'np:class',
 u'np:function',
 u'py:module',
 u'np-c:macro',
 u'np:exception',
 u'py:method',
 u'np:method',
 u'np-c:var',
 u'py:exception',
 u'np:staticmethod',
 u'py:staticmethod',
 u'c:type',
 u'np-c:type',
 u'c:macro',
 u'c:function',
 u'np:module',
 u'py:data',
 u'np:attribute',
 u'std:term',
 u'py:function',
 u'py:classmethod',
 u'py:attribute']
```

You can see how you can write your cross-reference when you look at the content of a specific domain. For example, `py:class`:

```
{u'numpy.DataSource': (u'NumPy',
  u'1.9',
  u'http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.DataSource.html#numpy.DataSource',
  u'-'),
 u'numpy.MachAr': (u'NumPy',
  u'1.9',
  u'http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.MachAr.html#numpy.MachAr',
  u'-'),
 u'numpy.broadcast': (u'NumPy',
  u'1.9',
  u'http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html#numpy.broadcast',
  u'-'),
  ...}
```

So here, `` :class:`numpy.DataSource` `` will work as expected.

### h5py

In the case of h5py, the domains are:

```
[u'py:attribute', u'std:label', u'py:method', u'py:function', u'py:class']
```

and if you look at the `py:class` domain:

```
{u'AttributeManager': (u'h5py',
  u'2.5',
  u'http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/attr.html#AttributeManager',
  u'-'),
 u'Dataset': (u'h5py',
  u'2.5',
  u'http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#Dataset',
  u'-'),
 u'ExternalLink': (u'h5py',
  u'2.5',
  u'http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#ExternalLink',
  u'-'),
 ...}
```

That's why I couldn't make it work as numpy references. So a good way to format them would be `` :class:`h5py:Dataset` ``.

### OpenCV

OpenCV's inventory object seems malformed. Where I would expect to find domains there is actually 902 function signatures:

```
[u':',
 u'AdjusterAdapter::create(const',
 u'AdjusterAdapter::good()',
 u'AdjusterAdapter::tooFew(int',
 u'AdjusterAdapter::tooMany(int',
 u'Algorithm::create(const',
 u'Algorithm::getList(vector<string>&',
 u'Algorithm::name()',
 u'Algorithm::read(const',
 u'Algorithm::set(const'
 ...]
```

and if we take the first one's value:

```
{u'Ptr<AdjusterAdapter>': (u'OpenCV',
  u'2.4',
  u'http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/detectorType)',
  u'ocv:function 1 modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#$ -')}
```

I'm pretty sure it is then impossible to write OpenCV cross-references with this file...

### Conclusion

I thought intersphinx generated the `objects.inv` based on the content of the documentation project in an *standard* way, which seems not to be the case.
As a result, it seems that the proper way to write cross-references is API dependent and one should inspect a specific inventory object to actually see what's available.

Comment: side note: opencv3 has removed all sphinx documentation (in favour of doxygen)

Comment: I'm trying to get a link to np.float_ and it's not working. I'm trying things like `:c:var:\`NPY_FLOAT\`` but sphinx complains of an 'unknown text role'.  If I use `:class:\`NPY_FLOAT\`` intersphinx doesn't lay in the link properly. Any thoughts? (Nice work here, btw!)

Comment: @Brian As I understand the Sphinx documentation, *Domains* are used to describe something and *Cross-references* are basically links to those resources. If you look at the [C domain](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#the-c-domain), you'll see that ``var`` is available as a *domain* (to describe a variable) but not as a *cross-reference*. In this case you have to use ``:c:data:`NPY_FLOAT` ``.

Comment: Mmph, `:c:data:` might be the one I didn't try. Pretty sure I tried `:c:attr:`, at least, and it didn't work.  I'll give `data` a shot... thanks!

Comment: Instead of writing this Python program which does not work anymore, the information can be extracted through running the intersphinx module as per [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36831198/1735594): python -m sphinx.ext.intersphinx FILE.inv

Comment: There's a guide to the syntax of the inventory here: in particular the format of each line of object data goes `{name} {domain}:{role} {priority} {uri} {dispname}` https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/sphobjinv/v.doc/sphobjinv.pdf

Answer (score 31):

In addition to the detailed answer from @gall, I've discovered that `intersphinx` can also be run as a module:

```
python -m sphinx.ext.intersphinx 'http://python-eve.org/objects.inv'
```

This outputs nicely formatted info.  For reference: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/ext/intersphinx.py#L390

Comment: Broken in Sphinx 1.4.3? I just get `intersphinx inventory 'http://docs.python.org/' not readable due to AttributeError: 'MockApp' object has no attribute 'info'`

Comment: It does work on a local file: `wget http://python-eve.org/objects.inv`, then `python -m sphinx.ext.intersphinx object.inv`

Comment: `python -m sphinx.ext.intersphinx 'http://python-eve.org/objects.inv'` works again in Sphinx 1.6.2.

Comment: And it [stopped working in 1.7.0](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4664).

Answer (score 5):

An additional way to inspect the `objects.inv` file is with the [sphobjinv](https://sphobjinv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module.

You can search local or even remote inventory files (with fuzzy matching). For instance with scipy:

```
$ sphobjinv suggest -t 90 -u https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/objects.inv "signal.convolve2d"

Remote inventory found.

:py:function:`scipy.signal.convolve2d`
:std:doc:`generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d`
```

Note that you may need to use `:py:func:` and not `:py:function:` (I'd be happy to know why).

Comment: Having to use `:func:` in cross-references instead of the `:function:` listed in the `objects.inv` is just an idiosyncrasy of the Python domain in Sphinx. All of this terminology is defined [here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/685e3fdb49c42b464e09ec955e1033e2a8729fff/sphinx/domains/python.py#L845-L881); you'd have to consult the docs for the underlying `docutils` to learn what all of the syntax is actually doing.

Comment: Here is also the relevant section of the documentation on how to reference Python objects: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#python-roles

Answer (score 3):

## How to use OpenCV 2.4 (cv2) intersphinx

Inspired by @Gall's answer, I wanted to compare the contents of the OpenCV & numpy inventory files. I couldn't get `sphinx.ext.intersphinx.fetch_inventory` to work from ipython, but the following does work:

```
curl http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/objects.inv | tail -n +5 | zlib-flate -uncompress > cv2.inv
curl https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/objects.inv | tail -n +5 | zlib-flate -uncompress > numpy.inv
```

numpy.inv has lines like this:

```
numpy.ndarray py:class 1 reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#$ -
```

whereas cv2.inv has lines like this:

```
cv2.imread ocv:pyfunction 1 modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#$ -
```

So presumably you'd link to the OpenCV docs with `` :ocv:pyfunction:`cv2.imread` `` instead of `` :py:function:`cv2.imread` ``. Sphinx doesn't like it though:

> WARNING: Unknown interpreted text role "ocv:pyfunction".

A bit of Googling revealed that the OpenCV project has its own "ocv" sphinx domain: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4/doc/ocv.py -- presumably because they need to document C, C++ and Python APIs all at the same time.

To use it, save `ocv.py` next to your Sphinx `conf.py`, and modify your `conf.py`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
import ocv
extensions = [
    'ocv',
]
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'cv2': ('http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/', None),
}
```

In your rst files you need to say `` :ocv:pyfunc:`cv2.imread` `` (not `:ocv:pyfunction:`).

Sphinx prints some warnings (`unparseable C++ definition: u'cv2.imread'`) but the generated html documentation actually looks ok with a link to http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv2.imread. You can edit `ocv.py` and remove the line that prints that warning.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer no longer works in the new version (1.5.x) ...

```
import requests
import posixpath
from sphinx.ext.intersphinx import read_inventory

uri = 'http://docs.python.org/2.7/'

r = requests.get(uri + 'objects.inv', stream=True)
r.raise_for_status()

inv = read_inventory(r.raw, uri, posixpath.join)
```

Comment: This answer does not work either (tested with 1.6.2): "ImportError: cannot import name read_inventory".

Comment: I was using 1.5.x at the time, so you're probably right. Want to submit an answer that works in 1.6.2?

Comment: The answer from @lingfish stopped working in 1.4.3. But it works again in 1.6.2.

Answer (score 2):

Stubborn fool that I am, I used `2to3` and the [Sphinx deprecated APIs chart](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/deprecated.html) to revive [@david-röthlisberger's `ocv.py`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45102339/435253) so it'll work with Sphinx 2.3 on Python 3.5.

The fixed-up version is here:

https://gist.github.com/ssokolow/a230b27b7ea4a31f7fb40621e6461f9a

...and the quick version of what I did was:

1. Run `2to3 -w ocv.py && rm ocv.py.bak`
2. Cycle back and forth between running Sphinx and renaming functions to their replacements in the chart. I believe these were the only changes I had to make on this step:

   1. `Directive` now has to be imported from `docutils.parsers.rst`
   2. Replace calls to `l_(...)` with calls to `_(...)` and remove the `l_` import.
3. Replace calls to `env.warn` with calls to `log.warn` where `log = sphinx.util.logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

Then, you just pair it with this intersphinx definition and you get something still new enough to be relevant for most use cases:

```
'cv2': ('https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, I made a small extension for aliasing intersphinx cross references.  This is useful as sometimes the object inventory gets confused when an object from a submodule is imported from a package's `__init__.py`.

See also https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5603

```py
###
# Workaround of
# Intersphinx references to objects imported at package level can"t be mapped.
#
# See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5603

intersphinx_aliases = {
    ("py:class", "click.core.Group"):
        ("py:class", "click.Group"),
    ("py:class", "click.core.Command"):
        ("py:class", "click.Command"),
}


def add_intersphinx_aliases_to_inv(app):
    from sphinx.ext.intersphinx import InventoryAdapter
    inventories = InventoryAdapter(app.builder.env)

    for alias, target in app.config.intersphinx_aliases.items():
        alias_domain, alias_name = alias
        target_domain, target_name = target
        try:
            found = inventories.main_inventory[target_domain][target_name]
            try:
                inventories.main_inventory[alias_domain][alias_name] = found
            except KeyError:
                print("could not add to inv")
                continue
        except KeyError:
            print("missed :(")
            continue


def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value("intersphinx_aliases", {}, "env")
    app.connect("builder-inited", add_intersphinx_aliases_to_inv)
```

To use this, I paste the above code in my `conf.py` and add aliases to the `intersphinx_aliases` dictionary.