# Linking external documentation in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I am trying to link from our project's extension documentation to the core documentation in Sphinx. I've  tried intersphinx, but from what I see it only supports objects, while our documentation doesn't refer to objects, it's just plain .rst.

I've added

```py
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'project': ('http://link-to-readthedocs/index.html', None),
}
```

to conf.py and edited the link to `` :ref:\`Documentation\` ``  and later `` :doc:\`Documentation\` `` . It didn't work.

The question:

**How to link from one projects' documentation to another in Sphinx for plain .rst files (not objects)?**

**Edit**: I've done `make html`, found my `objects.inv`, but now I guess I only have it locally? I'm not sure what I'm doing anymore, but when I try to check the [object references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939867/how-to-properly-write-coss-references-to-external-documentation-with-intersphinx), I get:

```
UserWarning: intersphinx inventory 'http://myproject.com/index.html/objects.inv' not fetchable due to <class 'urllib.error.HTTPError'>: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
  '%s: %s' % (inv, err.__class__, err))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to fix here is the link you've included to the base URL of your project docs:

> `intersphinx_mapping = {
>   'project': ('http://link-to-readthedocs/index.html', None),
>   }`

According to the [`intersphinx` docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html?highlight=intersphinx_mapping#confval-intersphinx_mapping):

> A dictionary mapping unique identifiers to a tuple `(target, inventory)`. Each `target` is the base URI of a foreign Sphinx documentation set and can be a local path or an HTTP URI. The `inventory` indicates where the inventory file can be found: it can be `None` (at the same location as the base URI) or another local or HTTP URI.

Thus, the error is in having the `index.html` at the end of your `target`. It should instead look something like this:

`intersphinx_mapping = {
  'project': ('http://project.readthedocs.io/en/latest', None),
  }`

If desired, replace `en` with the preferred docs language, and `latest` with the preferred RtD built version of the docs.