# How to properly link to PyQt5 documentation using intersphinx?

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-sphinx

I'm running into some trouble trying to link to the [PyQt5 docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/) using `intersphinx`.

Trying to cross reference any of the `QtCore` classes (such as `QThread`) does not work as I'd expect. I have parsed the `objects.inv` available [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/objects.inv) using `python -m sphinx.ext.intersphinx objects.inv`, which results in an output shown in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jat255/f1c86a41399d26ddf43b70ee8a6d6b92).

Unfortunately, under the python namespace there are no classes and only a few functions. Everything `PyQt5`-related is in the `sip:class` namespace. Trying to reference this in documentation using the standard `:py:class:` syntax does not link to anything (since sphinx doesn't see that reference connected to anything), and using `:sip:class:` causes a warning of `Unknown interpreted text role "sip:class"`, which makes sense because that is not a known reference code.

So, how do we access the documentation of PyQt through intersphinx (if we can at all)?

Comment: I do not think it is possible. Take a look at https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2013-March/032528.html where they mention about the limited inclusion of classes that can be referenced.

Comment: Well, nothing is impossible. It's a matter of submitting a PR to the project. See my answer to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45700546/2214933

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:
I create python package with this solution: https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-qt-documentation/

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I use another approach to this problem. I create custom sphinx plugin to translate on fly inventory file to use `sip` domain. It allows to chose which documentation should be pointed (pleas see docstring on top). It works on my project, but I'm not sure if it support all cases.

This extension need `sphinx.ext.intersphinx` extension to be configured in sphinx extension and `PyQt` configure in mapping

```py
intersphinx_mapping = {...,
                       "PyQt": ("https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5", None)}
```

```py
"""
This module contains sphinx extension supporting for build PartSeg documentation.

this extensio provides one configuration option:

`qt_documentation` with possibe values:

 * PyQt - linking to PyQt documentation on https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/ (incomplete)
 * Qt - linking to Qt documentation on "https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/" (default)
 * PySide - linking to PySide documentation on  "https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/"
"""
import re
from sphinx.application import Sphinx
from sphinx.environment import BuildEnvironment
from docutils.nodes import Element, TextElement
from docutils import nodes
from typing import List, Optional, Dict, Any
from sphinx.locale import _

from sphinx.ext.intersphinx import InventoryAdapter

try:
    from qtpy import QT_VERSION
except ImportError:
    QT_VERSION = None

# TODO add response to
#  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102004/how-to-properly-link-to-pyqt5-documentation-using-intersphinx

signal_slot_uri = {
    "Qt": "https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html",
    "PySide": "https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/signalsandslots.html",
    "PyQt": "https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html"
}

signal_name = {
    "Qt": "Signal",
    "PySide": "Signal",
    "PyQt": "pyqtSignal"
}

slot_name = {
    "Qt": "Slot",
    "PySide": "Slot",
    "PyQt": "pyqtSlot"
}

signal_pattern = re.compile(r'((\w+\d?\.QtCore\.)|(QtCore\.)|(\.)())?(pyqt)?Signal')
slot_pattern = re.compile(r'((\w+\d?\.QtCore\.)|(QtCore\.)|(\.)())?(pyqt)?Slot')

def missing_reference(app: Sphinx, env: BuildEnvironment, node: Element, contnode: TextElement
                      ) -> Optional[nodes.reference]:
    """Linking to Qt documentation."""
    target: str = node['reftarget']
    inventories = InventoryAdapter(env)
    objtypes = None  # type: Optional[List[str]]
    if node['reftype'] == 'any':
        # we search anything!
        objtypes = ['%s:%s' % (domain.name, objtype)
                    for domain in env.domains.values()
                    for objtype in domain.object_types]
        domain = None
    else:
        domain = node.get('refdomain')
        if not domain:
            # only objects in domains are in the inventory
            return None
        objtypes = env.get_domain(domain).objtypes_for_role(node['reftype'])
        if not objtypes:
            return None
        objtypes = ['%s:%s' % (domain, objtype) for objtype in objtypes]
    if target.startswith("PySide2"):
        head, tail = target.split(".", 1)
        target = "PyQt5." + tail
    obj_type_name = "sip:{}".format(node.get("reftype"))
    if obj_type_name not in inventories.named_inventory["PyQt"]:
        return None
    target_list = [target, "PyQt5." + target]
    target_list += [name + "." + target for name in inventories.named_inventory["PyQt"]["sip:module"].keys()]
    if signal_pattern.match(target):
        uri = signal_slot_uri[app.config.qt_documentation]
        dispname = signal_name[app.config.qt_documentation]
        version = QT_VERSION
    elif slot_pattern.match(target):
        uri = signal_slot_uri[app.config.qt_documentation]
        dispname = slot_name[app.config.qt_documentation]
        version = QT_VERSION
    else:
        for target_name in target_list:
            if target_name in inventories.main_inventory[obj_type_name]:
                proj, version, uri, dispname = inventories.named_inventory["PyQt"][obj_type_name][target_name]
                print(node)  # print nodes with unresolved references
                break
        else:
            return None
        if app.config.qt_documentation == "Qt":
            html_name = uri.split("/")[-1]
            uri = "https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/" + html_name
        elif app.config.qt_documentation == "PySide":
            html_name = "/".join(target.split(".")[1:]) + ".html"
            uri = "https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/" + html_name

    # remove this line if you would like straight to pyqt documentation
    if version:
        reftitle = _('(in %s v%s)') % (app.config.qt_documentation, version)
    else:
        reftitle = _('(in %s)') % (app.config.qt_documentation,)
    newnode = nodes.reference('', '', internal=False, refuri=uri, reftitle=reftitle)
    if node.get('refexplicit'):
        # use whatever title was given
        newnode.append(contnode)
    else:
        # else use the given display name (used for :ref:)
        newnode.append(contnode.__class__(dispname, dispname))
    return newnode


def setup(app: Sphinx) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    app.connect('missing-reference', missing_reference)
    app.add_config_value('qt_documentation', "Qt", True)
    return {
        'version': "0.9",
        'env_version': 1,
        'parallel_read_safe': True
    }
```

Comment: This would be great as a standalone sphinx extension. Have you considered releasing this separately from the project you use this in?

Comment: your welcome https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-qt-documentation/

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get `intersphinx` mapping to work for my project that uses PyQt5 I did the following:

1. Downloaded the original [objects.inv](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/objects.inv) file
2. Changed the `:sip:` domain to be `:py:`
3. Redirected the URL for most PyQt objects to point to the Qt website, which means that instead of being directed to [PyQt-QWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/QtWidgets/qwidget.html##PyQt5-QtWidgets-QWidget) when someone clicks on a `QWidget` in my documentation they are directed to [Qt-QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html)
4. Added aliases so that `` :class:`QWidget` ``, `` :class:`QtWidgets.QWidget` `` and `` :class:`PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget` `` are all linked to [Qt-QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html)

If you would like to use my modified `objects.inv` file in your own project you can [download](https://github.com/MSLNZ/msl-qt/blob/master/docs/pyqt5-modified-objects.inv) it, save it to the same directory as your `conf.py` file and then edit your `intersphinx_mapping` dictionary in your `conf.py` to be

```
    intersphinx_mapping = {
        # 'PyQt5': ('http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/', None),
        'PyQt5': ('', 'pyqt5-modified-objects.inv'),
    }
```

If my `'pyqt5-modified-objects.inv'` file does not meet the requirements for your project (for example, I did not add aliases for all Qt modules, only `QtWidgets`, `QtCore` and `QtGui`) then you can modify the [source code](https://github.com/MSLNZ/msl-qt/blob/master/docs/create_pyqt_objects.py) that automatically performs steps 1 - 4 above.

The source code can also be used to create a modified `objects.inv` file for PyQt4; however, the original `objects.inv` file for PyQt4 does not contain a complete listing of all Qt modules and classes and therefore using `intersphinx` mapping with PyQt4 isn't very useful.

*Note: The SourceForge team is currently solving some [issues](https://twitter.com/sfnet_ops/status/969377360129773568?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Ferror-404.html) and so executing the source code will raise a `ConnectionError` until their issues are resolved.*