# Sphinx: reference special methods

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Sphinx allows linking to external documentation (such as the standard library docs) via intersphinx.

Is it possible to link to the definition of special methods like [`__del__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__), without just making a regular link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link to root page in intersphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699577/how-to-link-to-root-page-in-intersphinx)

Comment: ehhhh... it kinda sorta suggests it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in my case, I just needed to link to the `object.__del__` method:

```
:py:meth:`__del__() <object.__del__>`
```

To do this generically:

1. Use `python -m sphinx.ext.intersphinx https://docs.python.org/3/objects.inv` to get the inventory of the python docs. You're gonna want to pipe the output through less or grep or save it to a file
2. Search through the results for the thing you're looking for. For special methods, it'll probably be `object.__spam__`
3. Look at the section the thing is under, and add it to your rst