# Link to See Also functions in Sphinx docstrings

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When I'm writing docstrings for my python packages, I just cannot make the functions appear in `See Also` section linkable, especially for the functions that belongs to other modules, could some one help me to fix this issue, thanks!

BTW, I'm following the numpy docstring rules, and all the API docs is generated from `sphinx-autogen`, below is a basic example:

In module `mod1`:

```
def f_add(x, y):
    """Return sum of two input numbers. 

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : float
        First input number.
    y : float
        Second input number.

    Returns
    -------
    s : float
        Sum of two input numbers.

    See Also
    --------
    f_mul : Multiply function.
    """
```

However `f_mul` is in another module: `mod2`, what is the right way to make `f_mul` in `See Also` of `f_add` linkable?

Updated:
`` :func:`f_mul` `` actually works, but not so neat in CLI.

Comment: You can try
*See Also**
.. seealso:: f_mul

Comment: @nick_gabpe That does not work either, only :func:`f_mul` works, but this way looks not neat in the command line interface environment.

Comment: @Tong Have you solved it since then? I have the same problem: I want to have links to built-in Python functions (e.g. `zipfile.ZipFile`), to third-party functions (e.g. `numpy.vstack`) and to my own functions from another module (e.g. `my_other_module.my_func`).

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti The following link would help you: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html

Comment: @Tong Thanks, that solved all my problems! For reference, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538983/specifying-targets-for-intersphinx-links-to-numpy-scipy-and-matplotlib).