# How to get sphinx to gracefully ignore 3rd party reference targets in intersphinx mappings

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I've run into issues a few times that are solved by `intersphinx_mapping`, but that can be [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42513684/534674).  I'm also wary of coupling my doc build success to another library's success, especially if I'm in charge of the other library.  Is there a way to tell sphinx to not build reference targets to modules outside my package, and just assume they are valid?  Alternatively, is there a way to list the ignored reference targets in conf.py?  That way, I could at least review the warnings, verify I do actually want to ignore them, and manually add them.

E.g. a subclass of numpy array that wants to prohibit assigning to `shape`, with the code:

```py
@property
def shape(self):
     return super().shape
```

In sphinx, this gives:

```
docstring of mypackage.MyArrayClass.shape:12: WARNING: 'any' reference target not found: ndarray.reshape
```

It is referring to the first link to `ndarray.reshape` in the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html).

Comment: Try using the linkcheck builder, see https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-the-linkcheck-builder